# Why my socket doesn't receive any message?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client

In my code, I have this snippet:

```
char temp_buff[2048] = "";
strcpy(temp_buff, json_object_to_json_string(hb));
printf("%s\n", temp_buff);

char *str;
int fd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in demoserverAddr, cliaddr;
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (fd < 0)
{
    debug_level > 0 && printf("[SKT]\tError creating socket\n");
}
else
{
    demoserverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    demoserverAddr.sin_port = htons(9100);
    demoserverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(demoserverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(demoserverAddr.sin_zero));
}
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

int len=sizeof(cliaddr);
sendto(fd, temp_buff, strlen(temp_buff),MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, len);
```

On the other side, I write `netcat -u -l 9100` in a terminal to see the incoming message, but nothing happens. Why?

Comment: Try `SOCK_DGRAM` for UDP instead of `SOCK_STREAM`

Comment: same thing, thank you anyway

Comment: Check the return value of `sendto` for errors. Otherwise, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to test.

Comment: error -1: invalid argument

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `demoserverAddr` and not `cliaddr` in the `sendto` call?

Comment: -1 means an error ocurred. *What* error? Print `errno`, or call `perror()`, or print `syserror()`. In any case it is clear evidence that nothing was *sent.*

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

First, by using `SOCK_STREAM` in the call to `socket` you're creating a TCP socket, but you're using `sendto` to and your netcat call is using the `-u` option indicating that you want to use UDP.  So use `SOCK_DGRAM` instead.

Second, you're specifying `cliaddr` as the address to send to, but that variable was zero'ed out by `memset`.  The `demoserverAddr` variable contains the IP and port of the remote server, so pass that to `sendto`.  Also, be sure to check the return value.

```
int len=sizeof(demoserverAddr);
int rval = sendto(fd, temp_buff, strlen(temp_buff),MSG_CONFIRM, 
                  (const struct sockaddr *)&demoserverAddr, len);
if (rval < 0) perror("sendto failed");
```

Comment: sendto failed: Invalid argument... why?

Comment: @ReportFeedback Did you copy the line above *exactly*?  Also, try `memset(demoserverAddr, '\0', sizeof(demoserverAddr));` before setting any fields of `demoserverAddr`.